# Select the second element of a dropdown list with Chrome Webdriver - Python

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I want to select the second element of "TIPOPARTICIPANTE" dropdown list in the following website with Chrome webdriver:

https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx

I can select the dropdown list, by the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\chromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe') # caminho onde o chromedriver.exe está
driver.get('https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx')

dropdown_list = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#s2id_cboTipoParticipante')
dropdown_list.click()

option = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li:nth-child(2)') 
option.click() # este comando gerou um erro 'ElementClickInterceptException'
```

However, in the last line of this script, I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 5, in 
> option2.click()
> File "C:\Users\Raphael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
> line 80, in click
> self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
> File "C:\Users\Raphael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
> line 633, in _execute
> return self._parent.execute(command, params)
> File "C:\Users\Raphael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> File "C:\Users\Raphael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)   ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element
> li class="select2-search-field".../li is not clickable at point
> (819, 118). Other element would receive the click: div
> id="select2-drop-mask" class="select2-drop-mask" style=""/div
> (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)

Can someone, please, help me select the second element ("Companhias Abertas") of this drop-down list?

Comment: Was the issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

1 Use explicit waits in your code:
For this import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

2 Wait until loader disappears. For this use: `invisibility_of_element_located` method.

3 Locator for the second option is `#select2-drop li:nth-child(3) div`, not `li:nth-child(2)`. There are six elements with locator you specified.

Description of locator:

`#select2-drop` - parent class with id `select2-drop`

`li:nth-child(3) div` Third child because first is `nth-child(3)`. div - you need a child of li.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id=divSplash]")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#s2id_cboTipoParticipante"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#select2-drop li:nth-child(3) div"))).click()
```

Result:
dropdown selected
[image]

Comment: `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable())` returns the element waited for so that line can be `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable()).click()` instead of two lines. Same for the second wait and `click()`. It would be much better if you used an XPath for the option in the dropdown to click it by contained text. You never know when the items in the dropdown will change or be reordered so choosing 3 today might be the right option but next week it may be incorrect and will be really hard to debug when something doesn't go as planned later in the script.

Comment: The option can be located using the XPath `//div[text()='Companhia Aberta']`.

Comment: @JeffC I agree that locating by text is a better option.

Comment: @JeffC, thank tou for this elegante solution.

Comment: Also, learned a lot with your answer, @vitaliis

Comment: You can accept the answer if the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `option` like this:

option = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.select2-match')[2]

Comment: Did you try this code? It's not working for me.